# Mocking model.User using mixer throughs error

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django, django-mixer

Im trying to add unit test for my Django project. Im using mixer to mock the models.
The model looks as below

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Mytable(Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='username')
    ...
    ...
```

My testcase looks like

```
class MyTest:
    def test_test1(self):
        mock_user = mixer.blend('django.contrib.auth.models.User')
        stock_mock = mixer.blend('app.Mytable', username=mock_user)
```

But im hitting "too many values to unpack" while mocking User model

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/kketan/Documents/projects/Extractor/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mixer/main.py", line 566, in blend
    type_mixer = self.get_typemixer(scheme)
  File "/Users/kketan/Documents/projects/Extractor/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mixer/main.py", line 583, in get_typemixer
    return self.type_mixer_cls(
  File "/Users/kketan/Documents/projects/Extractor/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mixer/main.py", line 47, in __call__
    cls_type = cls.__load_cls(cls_type)
  File "/Users/kketan/Documents/projects/Extractor/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mixer/backend/django.py", line 137, in __load_cls
    app_label, model_name = cls_type.split(".")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Am I mocking the models right way ? If yes is this error known ? If no can you please suggest better way ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://mixer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#django-orm) of mixer:

> You can use class or string with model name.
>
> [1]   Model name supports two formats. Use ‘app_name.model_name’ for
> preventing conflicts. Or you can use just ‘model_name’ for models with
> unique names.

Hence the format in which you write the model name is incorrect. You need to write it in the form `<pp_name>.<model_name>`. Hence instead of `'django.contrib.auth.models.User'` you need to write `'auth.User'`:

```
class MyTest:
    def test_test1(self):
        mock_user = mixer.blend('auth.User')
        stock_mock = mixer.blend('app.Mytable', username=mock_user)
```

Comment: Im hitting auth not found. should I add python path till auth ? also auth is not created my me. its default auth app provided by django

Comment: @ketankhandagale do you not have `django.contrib.auth.models.User` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting? Also add the _full_ stack trace of this error to your question. Did you perchance try _importing_ in this manner (`from auth import User`) or something? If so that won't work, this is only for referring to models as strings in fks and few other places.

Comment: yes i have added that in settings.. but still same error.